# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when adding svn branch to bash prompt

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm trying to add SVN and git branch to bash prompt. The code I'm adding to `bashrc` is

```
parse_git_branch () {
  git name-rev HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed ’s#HEAD\ (.*)# (git::\1)#‘
}
parse_svn_branch() {
  parse_svn_url | sed -e ’s#^’“$(parse_svn_repository_root)”‘##g’ | awk ‘{print “ (svn::”$1")“ }’
}
parse_svn_url() {
  svn info 2>/dev/null | sed -ne ’s#^URL: ##p'
}
parse_svn_repository_root() {
  svn info 2>/dev/null | sed -ne ’s#^Repository Root: ##p'
}


BLACK=“[\033[0;38m]”
RED=“[\033[0;31m]”
RED_BOLD=“[\033[01;31m]”
BLUE=“[\033[01;34m]”
GREEN=“[\033[0;32m]”



export PS1=“$BLACK[ \u@$RED\h $GREEN\w$RED_BOLD\$(parse_git_branch)\$(parse_svn_branch)$BLACK ] ”
```

The source came from:
https://hocuspokus.net/2009/07/add-git-and-svn-branch-to-bash-prompt/

The problem is that I am getting a syntax error message saying

```
-bash: /home/mark/.bashrc: line 125: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/mark/.bashrc: line 125: `  git name-rev HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed ’s#HEAD\ (.*)# (git::\1)#‘'
```

When I open up the file in atom text editor I can see that `#` after `(.*)` has been treated as a comment hence removing everything after that. ie `(git::\1)#'` has been treated as a comment.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your script appears to have typographic `’smart quotes‘` in place of regular single quotes. As well, `(.*)` is not a capture group in basic regular expression syntax - you'll need either `\(.*\)` or switch to extended expressions (`sed -E` or `sed -r`)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with is that you have used typographical “smart quotes“

```
’ “
```

in place of regular ASCII quotes

```
'  "
```

throughout your script. Because the shell doesn't recognise them as quoting characters, it is trying to parse your `sed` commands as shell commands and failing.

Once you fix that, your script should run - however you will likely get an error from `sed` like

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

from your command

```
sed 's#HEAD\ (.*)# (git::\1)#'
```

since `(` and `)` don't delimit a capture group in basic regular expression (BRE) syntax. Instead, you need `\(` and `\)`

```
sed 's#HEAD \(.*\)# (git::\1)#'
```

(the space character doesn't actually need to be backslash-escaped); or you can switch to extended regular expression (ERE) mode using `-E` or `-r`

```
sed -E 's#HEAD (.*)# (git::\1)#'
```